# Two log4net configuration files on same solution

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I have an solution which consist of multiple projects.its a desktop application  I need to have two separate log4net configurations for those projects since one project contains a library that uses log4net itself.  On one project log4net configured in App.config and other project it is configured in log4net.configuration file.

below is one configuration file
'''

```
<configSections>

    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ColoredConsoleAppender"/>
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="D:\seperatelog.txt"/>
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>

      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="'On_'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="14" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger: %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ColoredConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger: %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
      <to value="bobby.chopra@prcm.com"/>
      <from value="TagFileUploader@prcm.com"/>
      <subject value="TagFileUploader ERROR"/>
      <smtpHost value="prc-mn-ex01"/>
      <bufferSize value="512"/>
      <lossy value="true"/>
      <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="ERROR"/>
      </evaluator>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger: %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="cargillsJournal" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="D:\BankInABoxffffff-log.txt"/>
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="'On_'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="14" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger: %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

Other configuration file is below

```
      <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="console" />     
    </root>
    <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="rolling-log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <header value="[Header]&#13;&#10;" />
        <footer value="[Footer]&#13;&#10;" />
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="LoggingExample">
      <!-- <appender-ref ref="B" /> -->
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </logger>
   </log4net>
```

those two log file load correctly but they all write on to the same log file seperatelog.txt

What i need is to have two separate files to create for those 2 configurations.

Comment: Both projects run as separate exe?

Comment: No there's only one exe

Comment: Is the second project type a library? If so, it probably has its own namespace, correct? You can copy the appender def into the first config and create a logger for that lib's namespace.

Comment: Yes it is a library project.  That library is use to write an activity log. I setup the logger on app.config as                                                                                       <logger name="LoggingExample">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="EJournals.RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </logger>                                                                                                                here EJournals is the library name

Answer (score 0):

Seems you'll better define log4net configuration not in app.config but in dedicated XML files. Names of XML files can be composed according to some convention so your projects will know what log4net configuration XML is dedicated to each one.

You'll able to configure your log4net with XmlConfigurator.Configure(...) function